# Multi Screen Wallpaper not using Zoom setting at login

Tags: multiple-monitors, login, desktop-background, zooming

Two monitors, one rotated (which seems to be a factor here) and the wallpaper will not properly use the zoom setting at log in.  It has the appearance of being in span mode at log in.  A simple change from the current zoom setting to something else, then back to zoom again will fix the problem.  I can also use the following as a startup application to fix it but seems like a hack.

```
#!/bin/bash
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-options 'spanned'
sleep 1;
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-options 'zoom'
```

Comment: I have the same issue now (16.04). Didn't see it before! I use your script as startup application now, need to `sleep 5` at the beginning and `sleep 0.2` in between works for me. Works well, but I'd like to see a proper solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could add the following to crontab. Run this:

```
crontab -e
```

and edit it to have the line:

```
@reboot gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-options 'zoom'
```

or

```
@reboot ./scripttochangeit.sh
```